# Using my Time capsule to improve WiFi from my network supplied modem

Tags: wifi, time-capsule

We've recently moved house and now I have a Macbook Pro, a 2009 Time Capsule and an ADSL modem/router from our network supplier, Telstra. The Telstra modem doesn't have enough grunt/range to reach another room for me to use my iPad there. In a previous house we connected the Time Capsule to another type of Telstra modem by Ethernet cable and the Time Capsule acted as router. It sent the signal throughout a two storey house.
Can I do the same with this setup and what do I have do on the Macbook to make it all work?

Comment: Yes, you can use the Time Capsule as a router.

Comment: I understand that I can do it. It's the how I need.

Comment: Roger :). I'll post a guide for you tomorrow.

Comment: Ok, I've posted a detailed guide for you. Please let me know how it works!

Comment: Fantastic. Thanks. That's sorted the Time Capsule to be the WiFi. Now I have to get stronger WiFi to other rooms through brick walls. The TC is a bit weak. I've been told to get a Powerline that connects Time Capsule and another Wifi device in the other room. I already have a Powerline from modem to Foxtel.

Comment: Nice. Glad I could help (you can click the checkmark if you think my answer helped you!). Using an extender can be unreliable, especially in a big house with brick walls like you have, and speeds will still drop off between the TC and the extender. Certainly try it, but if it doesn't work too well (there ended up being tons of reliability issues when I did a very similar setup in my apartment), a mesh network would probably help. Though expensive, [Eero](https://eero.com) works amazingly for me (you get 3 boxes and they all wirelessly talk to each other to make a mesh network)!

Answer (score 1):

It is certainly possible to set up your Time Capsule as your sole router even when your modem is a router/modem combo.

### Setup

**Part 1: setting up the Time Capsule normally**

1. Download Airport Utility on your Mac (if you already have downloaded it, ensure it's version 5.3 or later).
2. Connect your Telstra modem to the WAN port of your Time Capsule via an Ethernet cable.
3. Connect the Time Capsule's power cable to an AC outlet.
4. Open the Airport Utility app on your Mac (search Spotlight for it or go to the `Utilities` subfolder of your `Applications` folder).
5. The Time Capsule will have an initial name (such as "Time Capsule fea88c"). Click continue to proceed.
6. Select "Create a new wireless network" and click Continue.
7. Follow the rest of the on-screen instructions (you'll probably want to use the same SSID/Password for your new network as your old one had). When finished, your Time Capsule will restart and apply your settings.

Now your Time Capsule is broadcasting WiFi. Problem is, so is your Telstra router/modem.

**Part 2: turning off the router portion of the Telstra.**

8. Find your Telstra router's local IP address ([this page](https://crowdsupport.telstra.com.au/t5/Modems-Hardware/BigPond-Modem-settings/td-p/17262) might help). NOTE: It is *probably* 10.0.0.138, but may also be 192.168.0.1 (or something else even!).
9. Type this IP address into your browser's address bar.
10. You should see a setup page for your Telstra router/modem (if you don't, you have the wrong IP address from step 8).
11. Find the `WI-FI` section: [image: setup page]
12. In the WI-FI section, navigate to *both* the 2.4 GHz and 5 GHz tabs, and in each **uncheck** `Enabled`.
13. Test that you successfully disabled your Telstra modem/router's routing capabilities by unplugging the Time Capsule. If your internet connection drops, and your devices go offline, you're all set.
14. Plug your Time Capsule back in and enjoy.

---

Your sole router should now be the Time Capsule. If any step goes wrong, feel free to leave a comment below so I can assist you further. Thanks!

---

**Sources and more information**

- [Setting up Time Capsule normally, an Apple Support article.](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201510)
- [Accessing Telstra router settings, a Telstra forum.](https://crowdsupport.telstra.com.au/t5/Modems-Hardware/BigPond-Modem-settings/td-p/17262)
- [Turning off WiFi broadcasting of a Telstra router, a Telstra forum.](https://crowdsupport.telstra.com.au/t5/Modems-Hardware/can-i-turn-off-the-wi-fi-with-with-a-telstra-gateway-max-modem/td-p/488711)